# kubectl "failed to negotiate an api version"

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

Hello since yesterday morning I'm running into issues trying to access one of my Kubernetes cluster hosted on Google container engine. I had never had problem until it started to fail but now each kubectl command I try to execute fails by telling "error: failed to negotiate an api version;".

i.e:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"3", GitVersion:"v1.3.4",
GitCommit:"dd6b458ef8dbf24aff55795baa68f83383c9b3a9", GitTreeState:"clean",
BuildDate:"2016-08-01T16:45:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.2", Compiler:"gc",
Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
error: failed to negotiate an api version; server supports: map[], client
supports: map[v1:{} apps/v1alpha1:{} autoscaling/v1:{} componentconfig/v1alpha1:{} 
batch/v1:{} batch/v2alpha1:{} authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1:{} federation/v1beta1:{} 
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1:{} authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1:{} extensions/v1beta1:{} 
policy/v1alpha1:{}]
```

I have tried to delete then recreate my cluster without success and I made sure the kubernetes version are the same on the server and on the client (1.3.4). I can see the pool of instance running in the google cloud console as well as the cluster when I go to the container engine tab but I have little clue how to proceed from here, can anyone give me some light on what might going on?

Many thanks! Fabrice.

Comment: Did you set a custom user name (other than admin) when you created your cluster? Did you try to authenticate using a cluster certificate?

Answer (score 2):

I have been fighting with this issue for a few days, but finally found a solution that worked for me. I wanted to "start over" from the very beginning because I was suspicious that my configuration was broken/"poisoned," but I'm not sure which (if any) of the first 8 steps were truly necessary:

1. Backup the existing configuration for gcloud and kubectl

   - `mv ~/.kube/config ~/.kube/config.old`
   - `mv ~/.config ~/.config.old`
2. Delete the google cloud sdk

   - `rm -rf ~/bin/google-cloud-sdk`
3. Remove the lines from my `~/.bash_profile` that were added during the prior installation process using a text editor (one line that sets `PATH` and one line that enables bash completion)
4. Download [the latest google cloud sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)
5. Unpack the archive and run the `install.sh` script
6. Run `gcloud init` and follow the instructions it gives

   - I answered "y" for everything (configure for use with google container engine, modify the .bash_profile, and enable bash completion), but minimally you should configure it for use with google container engine
7. `gcloud components install kubectl`
8. gcloud container clusters get-credentials

When I ran `kubectl version` at this point, I got a different error! This is what I refer to as "progress." Now it told me that "google could not find the default credentials" and to follow the instructions at [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials). Briefly:

9. Create the service account as described, download the .json key, and move it to a directory of your choosing
10. Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the path to the key you downloaded
11. Install the gcloud beta component (`gcloud components install beta`)
12. Run `gcloud beta auth application-default login`

After that, `kubectl version` worked again! Hope this works for you, too.