# Error from kubectl with google cloud container engine

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I have installed the Google Cloud tools on my Linux box as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#linux) with:

1. `curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | sudo bash`
2. `sudo gcloud init`
3. `sudo gcloud components install kubectl beta`

So far so good. However when I run `kubectl` I get the error

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
error: failed to negotiate an api version; server supports: map[], client supports: map[batch/v2alpha1:{} policy/v1alpha1:{} rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1:{} authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1:{} authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1:{} componentconfig/v1alpha1:{} autoscaling/v1:{} v1:{} apps/v1alpha1:{} batch/v1:{} extensions/v1beta1:{} federation/v1beta1:{}]
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong or what I have to configure?

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/798670/kubectl-failed-to-negotiate-an-api-version ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a version mismatch. What's the `gcloud version` that you have?

If you want to install `kubectl`, you should install using [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux) to get the latest version (also, apt and the gcloud component manager don't play nice together).